# A website as a cross platform mobile application?

Tags: android, iphone, html, windows-phone-7, web-applications

I'm trying to develop a cross platform social networking mobile application for iPhone, WindowsPhone, and Android. I have a background with web development, so I was wondering if it was possible if I could make a web application and use the phones to load the website (using something like WebView in Android) when the user launches the applicaion.

I'm fairly new the mobile application development so I'm not sure if that's a possibility. Because, if it is, I would surely want to go that way and make web-loader kind-of applications on all the three platforms and have them load up the web when the user launches the app.

I wanted to know if that is possible, or not. Or has someone tried anything similar.

Added after edit:
I'm aware that there are many frameworks out there that are for this purpose, but Its not possible for me to learn them to implement this. It's kind-of an academic project, that I want to complete asap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just add a webview and voilà :P
Look at the old facebook app in Android, or the memondo apps...they are all based on a WebView.

The main problem with it is that **your app will suck**, because it will look like a website even if you make it right.

Comment: "Why does this Android app have an iPhone back button!!"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, now that you've mentioned it, I remember the old facebook app.

And sucking is not the issue, I just wanted to know if it's going to work as I tell it to :D.

Also, do you know of any similar widget like WebView in iPhone or Windows Phone?

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) ,With sencha touch you can build a site as well as it support Multiple Mobile Platform,
Or build a website with responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible for an app to launch a website, but the question is why would users want to download and install an app which simply points to a website?

If you make the website responsive you would not need an app in the first place.

Comment: I just want the app behave like it behaves on the web. I'm not really concerned about anything else at the moment, due to the nature of the project :P

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions, a popular and easy to use one of them  is [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Sencha touch is easy to learn for web developer as it contains majorly concept of Web development.So i should say go with Sencha Touch

Answer (score 0):

I think the one of the best ways to do this is to develop an HTML5/CSS3 web app/site (maybe with jQuery Mobile) and compile it with PhoneGap to generate native apps.